# How to get the results of a dynamic created SQL in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, dynamic, sys-refcursor

I'm struggling with a cursor.

I currently have following query:

```
DECLARE
    rc SYS_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN
    OPEN rc FOR SELECT
    sro.sysrepobject_id,
    sro.name as sysrepobject_name,
    configtrace.object_id,
    upper(nvl(sro.dbtablename,sro.name)) as table_name,
    upper(sra.dbcolumnname) as column_name
FROM
    configtrace
    LEFT OUTER JOIN sysrepobject sro ON sro.sysrepobject_id = configtrace.sysrepobject_id
    INNER JOIN sysrepattribute sra ON sra.sysrepobject_id = sro.sysrepobject_id and sra.representation = 1
WHERE
    configtrace.task = 'Task_1';

    dbms_sql.return_result(rc);
END;
/
```

It contains a list of all objects that have been changed in our program for a certain task 'Task_1'.

The result can look like this:

```
SYSREPOBJECT_ID SYSREPOBJECT_NAME                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           OBJECT_ID TABLE_NAME                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 COLUMN_NAME                   
--------------- ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- ---------- ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- ------------------------------
             93 Selection                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     1000158 SELECTION                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  DESCRIPTION                   
             93 Selection                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     1000158 SELECTION                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  DESCRIPTION                   
             93 Selection                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     1000158 SELECTION                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  DESCRIPTION                   
             93 Selection                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     1000158 SELECTION                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  DESCRIPTION                   
             93 Selection                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     1000158 SELECTION                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  DESCRIPTION                   
             94 SysRepEnumerationValue                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         402100 SYSENUMERATION                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             DESCRIPTION                   
            457 BulkProcessor                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 1000300 BULKPROCESSOR                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              NAME                          
            457 BulkProcessor                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 1000322 BULKPROCESSOR                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              NAME                          
            457 BulkProcessor                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 1000300 BULKPROCESSOR                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              NAME                          
            457 BulkProcessor                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 1000321 BULKPROCESSOR                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              NAME                          
            457 BulkProcessor                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 1000321 BULKPROCESSOR                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              NAME
```

The first column "Sysrepobject_id" is the ID of the type of object (e.g. 93 is for Selection, 457 is for a BulkProcessor).
The second column is the name of the type.
The third column is for the ID of the specific object, e.g. 1000158 is the ID of a specific selection.

What I would like to do is add an extra column with the name of e.g. the specific selection or the specific bulkprocessor.
To do that, I need to make an extra join to the specific SELECTION or BULKPROCESSOR table.
I already added these in my query, both the tablename and the column name that I want to look for.
Only problem I have is how I do this.

What I want is that oracle executes following queries after each other and print the result:

```
SELECT
    sro.sysrepobject_id,
    sro.name as sysrepobject_name,
    configtrace.object_id,
    selection.description
FROM
    configtrace
    LEFT OUTER JOIN sysrepobject sro ON sro.sysrepobject_id = configtrace.sysrepobject_id
    INNER JOIN sysrepattribute sra ON sra.sysrepobject_id = sro.sysrepobject_id and sra.representation = 1
    LEFT OUTER JOIN selection ON selection.selection_id = configtrace.object_id
WHERE
    configtrace.task = 'Task_1'
    and configtrace.sysrepobject_id = 93;
    
SELECT
    sro.sysrepobject_id,
    sro.name as sysrepobject_name,
    configtrace.object_id,
    SYSENUMERATION.name
FROM
    configtrace
    LEFT OUTER JOIN sysrepobject sro ON sro.sysrepobject_id = configtrace.sysrepobject_id
    INNER JOIN sysrepattribute sra ON sra.sysrepobject_id = sro.sysrepobject_id and sra.representation = 1
    LEFT OUTER JOIN SYSENUMERATION ON SYSENUMERATION.SYSENUMERATION_id = configtrace.object_id
WHERE
    configtrace.task = 'Task_1'
    and configtrace.sysrepobject_id = 94;   
    
SELECT
    sro.sysrepobject_id,
    sro.name as sysrepobject_name,
    configtrace.object_id,
    BulkProcessor.name
FROM
    configtrace
    LEFT OUTER JOIN sysrepobject sro ON sro.sysrepobject_id = configtrace.sysrepobject_id
    INNER JOIN sysrepattribute sra ON sra.sysrepobject_id = sro.sysrepobject_id and sra.representation = 1
    LEFT OUTER JOIN BulkProcessor ON BulkProcessor.BulkProcessor_id = configtrace.object_id
WHERE
    configtrace.task = 'Task_1'
    and configtrace.sysrepobject_id = 457;
```

Does someone know how I can do this dynamically?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you just call `dbms_sql.return_result(rc1); dbms_sql.return_result(rc2);` etc, or does each results depend on the previous one somehow?

Comment: Hi, sorry I don't understand what you mean. How would it look like?

Comment: I mean call `dbms_sql.return_result` once for each cursor. I didn’t really understand all the business logic though so might be missing a reason why you can’t do that.